# Implementing Logic in Base Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

Inside each of the Actions in my Controller, I utilize the following code:

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Details(string source, string id)
    {
        var max = Helpers.GetSource(source);
        if (max == null)
            return Content("Please check your request URL format, there is no source defined for your input");

        using (var cmax = new CMax(max.ConnectionString))
        {
```

I would like to be able to embed the base functionality, and have all Actions take Source by default, as well as generate a 'max' object as well as wrap the body of my Action function within my using statement.

Is it possible to implement this functionality into the base class, so that I do not have this redundant code in every action?

Comment: As another option, you could create an action filter and annotate your action with it.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Comment: I was hoping to implement it in the base class, so I implement it once, not in every Action.

Comment: @AdamReed you can apply action filters globally in `Application_Start` with this line of code `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyBaconActionFilterAttribute());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method I found best to implement this is to override OnActionExecuting.

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _max = Helpers.GetSource(Request.QueryString["source"]);

        if (_max == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result =
                Content("Please check your request URL format, there is no source defined for your input");
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

This allows me to define _max at the Class Level instead of at the Action Level, and implement checking logic again at the Class Level.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own base class that inherits `Controller`, that your controllers inherit from.

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller
{ 
    protected void SomeCommonMethod()
    {
         ....
    }
}

public class HomeController : MyBaseController
{
    public void Index()
    {
         SomeCommonMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Create a global action filter

```
public class MyBaconActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Some code here

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);            
    }
}
```

Then register it in the `global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Register global filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyBaconActionFilterAttribute());

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

This will now run for all action methods without the need to touch any of the controllers.